# Only horizontally spacing cells in email friendly HTML

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have a `<table>` in an HTML template, in which I want to space cell only horizontally. I have tried using `<div>`s is not an option as email clients are harsh on styling. Using `cellspacing` spaces cells equally vertically, which is unwanted.
I am open for dropping table and use divs or any other tag, I couldn't find any. I basically have only two cells (and only one row) in the table, and want to space them away.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: +1 @Joy_S. Also, do you want to have the two columns of equal width or do you want space in between?

Comment: After finding out the solution now I feel the question is not so good :P, you (all who are reading this) can vote to close it :), if you think noone will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this. I just added another `<td width="40%">` and it worked.

Comment: <td style="width:40%;">

Comment: @vignesh: styles are not encouraged in email html. Email clients ignore many styles. You should attributes if possible as they are guaranteed to not being ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Css can achieve it:

```
<style>
    td
    {
        padding-left:70px;
        padding-right:70px;
    }
</style>
```

Or if `style` tag doesn't work here is the inline CSS to do the same-

```
<td style="padding-left:70px; padding-right:70px;">
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LfNDB/)**

Comment: Padding property doesn't work in `gmail`. It gets completely ignored. Most other email clients behave similarly.

Comment: In fact if you use a style tag, the whole of it gets ignored. You have to use inline styling. Please read the question, it's not about any html, it's specifically about email.

Comment: Sorry but its a context dependent question. Does it really deserve a downvote? Works fine in a stand-alone webpage there is a demo, check it there please. Sorry if it didn't solve ur problm but tried to give u a direction.

Comment: @0xc0de padding does work in Gmail, but only inline, like all CSS needs to be. The issue is that the style tag does not render.

Comment: To further @John's response, here's a handy chart on email capabilities: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @RajeshPaul: If I had such an answer, I wouldn't complain as I don't think whether the question is specific or not, I would worry if my answer is answering the question or just is posting something I want to. I (and most of the SO users) already know what you answered, that's very basic, such a Q would be -5. I am sorry to ask a question that your answer doesn't answer to. I reversed my downvote.